# AWS EC2 - SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Working with aws ec2 locally. An error occurs, but I'm not sure why.

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

I opened port 3306 and deleted DB-related information `in application.yml`.

The AWS deployment process is in progress, and the development environment is using Spring Boot and MySQL. I think it's the reason the DB connection doesn't work, so I'm only thinking about that. Could it be another reason?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:74) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.ja


    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:468) ~[mysql-connetor-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:213) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1430) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:134) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:839) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
            ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What were you actually doing? It looks like you were trying to connect to a database? What software were you using? Please Edit your Question to add more details rather than just giving an error message.